# Does a nested class definition of a template class belong in an ipp file?

Tags: c++

Suppose I have a templated class that, for whatever reason beyond the scope of this question, has a nested class declaration:

```
// outer.hpp

template <typename T>
class Outer
{
  class X;

  void foo(); // this is defined in an ipp file
};

// should this also go into the ipp file?
template <typename T>
class Outer<T>::X
{
};
```

I'm a bit confused about where I should be putting the definition of `X`. Does it belong in the `ipp` file along with the member function definitions, or does it make sense for it to be in the header file?

Answer (score 0):

Just to be clear, it doesn't matter as far as compilation goes.

In general, all declarations should be in the header because this will maintain the pattern that the usage of your class can be found in a header.

For example, if you use Doxygen, you will want it to generate documentation about your inner class ( without having to change settings ).

Comment: *all definitions should be in the header* - do you mean all _declarations_? If not, could you elaborate, as I thought common practice was to place definitions into the `ipp` file?

Comment: Yes, edited, sorry about that.  Although, I've never used an ipp file myself.  Just prefer template code in one place.

Comment: Ok, so what about the definition of `X` - should it stay in the header or go into the `ipp` file with the rest of the definitions?

Comment: @quant Does it really matter all that much? Aren't you going to #include the ipp file at the bottom of the hpp file anyway? If you must split your template definition between two files, just go with whatever organization you feel adds benefit. There's no set rule to doing this.

Comment: @Praetorian as with all style questions; it probably doesn't matter all that much, but many programmers have more experiences than I so I tend to be wary of developing my own style patterns before asking about the potential pitfalls.